# Не получается сохранить сессию в node

Tags: node.js, express

Создаю сессию, в условии где она создается - вроде все получилось, в консоль ее вывожу - все ок, но если обращаюсь к ней в другом месте - ее нет.
После того как я создаю сессию, я возвращаюсь на /auth но в консоль ее не выводит, выводит андефайн
В чем проблема?

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      mysql = require('mysql'),
      connection = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 10,
        host: '****',
        user: 'dfsdf',
        password: '9696GORYACHEV',
        database: 'pcnumber'
      }),
      port = 3000,
      clientSessions = require('client-sessions'),
      path = require('path'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    let admins = [];

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/pages'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    connection.getConnection((err,connect) => {
      if(err){
        return console.log('Ошибка соединения с базой ' + err);
      }
      console.log('Подключение к базе успешно');
    });

    app.use(clientSessions({
      secret: 'ddsfs2fwfwf',
      cookieName: 'qwe',
      requestKey: 'session',
    }));

    app.get('/auth',(request,response,next) => {
      if(request.session.login){
        console.log(request.session.login);
        response.redirect('/pcnumber');
      }else{
        response.render('auth');
        console.log(request.session.login);
      }
    });

    app.get('/verif', (request, response, next) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE login LIKE ?',[request.query.login],(error, result, fields) => {
        if(result.length == 0){
          response.redirect('/auth');
          console.log('Неверный логин');
        }else{
          if(result[0].login == request.query.login && result[0].password == request.query.passwd){
            request.session.login = request.query.login;
            console.log(request.session.login);
          }else{
            response.redirect('/auth');
            console.log('Неверный логин или пароль');
          }
        }
      });

    });
```